# sed — Multine, curlybrackets, search replace

Tags: regex, sed

If want to replace all:

```
if (err) {
    callback(err);
    return;
}
```

With:

```
if (err) return callback(err);
```

In my code.

Using sed, I was looking for something like:

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/if\s*\(err\)\s*{\s*callback\(err\);\s*return;\s*}/if \(err\) return callback\(err\);/g;p;}'
```

As described here: http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/

But it doesn't seems to work. Any idea?

Comment: And what about nested curly brackets?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Actually if you can do perl or awk for this I would be happy to use it.

Comment: @anubhava hopefully there isn't curlybrackets inside this code but it might around.

Comment: I have also tried: `perl -i -p0e 's/if (err) {\n\s*callback(err);\n\s*return;\s*}/if (err) return callback(err);/smg'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with other posters that there are better alternatives for `sed`, but in case you are curious: the fault was in the parentheses. These should not be escaped with a backslash, as this causes them to be handled as grouping symbols, rather than literal parentheses.

This works fine:

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/if\s*(err)\s*{\s*callback(err);\s*return;\s*}/if (err) return callback(err);/g;p;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Through Perl,

```
$ cat file
foo
if (err) {
    callback(err);
    return;
}
bar
$ perl -0pe 's/(if *(\(err\))) *{\s*(callback)\2;\s*(return);\s*}/$1 $4 $3$2;/g' file
foo
if (err) return callback(err);
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl I was able to do it:

```
perl -i -p0e 's/if \(err\) \{\n\s*callback\(err\)\;\n\s*return;\s*}/if \(err\) return callback\(err\)\;/smg' my_file
```